# Simple WHERE OR query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Take a look here.
https://i.gyazo.com/3e84e8d01cbcd7e29a30bb998cc8e30d.png

I have a query that attempts to get some blogs, `published = 1` means its published, and if `published = 2` then that means its a draft until that date has come

For some reason I can't get it to work.

It should not be returning the row (id 3) because publish_date is tomorrow, but it still does

Comment: It's working absolutely fine. whats the issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be returning the first row, as the publish date is 2016-01-03 (tomorrow) and todays date is 2016-01-02

Comment: @BenShepherd . . . That depends on where you are.  There are users on this site all over the world, at at most times, there are two different dates in some timezones.

Comment: Plaese put your query and data in the question and in text form, not as an image, otherwise when the image will be deleted the question will become unreadable

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to just see drafted blogs which was either drafter today or in the past, then you should do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM blogs
WHERE published = 1
OR (publish_date <= CURDATE() AND published = 2)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10 offset 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `>=` to `<=`. You want the publish date to be in the past.

You should not be hard-coding the date, though, you should be checking against the current date.